# How to attach async file uploads to models with Carrierwave, Backbone, Plupload?

Tags: file-upload, backbone.js, carrierwave, plupload

Im trying to achieve what's talked about in the first 5 minutes of the Thoughtbot Q/A talk; Upload a file async and then persist the model with the file attached to it.

http://ui.thoughtbot.com/assets/backbone_js_rails_chat_episode_1_part_1.m4a

I've set up carrierwave on the backend and Plupload on the client and am able to make the request and upload the file. However I'm unsure about how I would send the token being talked about back in the response and then persist the model.

So I have a form with a title input and a plupload button that adds the image, I then have a save button that's supposed to make the upload, then save the model (Photo, with a mounted Carrierwave uploader and a title attribute)

How would I combine the two requests into being submitted on one single button?
How would all this be implemented ?

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe target (the upload) is on the same server you can return something analogous to a JSONP.  something like

```
var functionUpload(model, $inputform) {
   var cbName = 'cb' + Math.floor((Math.random()*100000)+1));
   document[cbName] = function (id) {
     model.set({binID: id}); // or just refetch
   } 
   $inputform.attr('action', uploadURL+'callback='cbName);
   $inputform.trigger('submit');
}
```

Then have the upload script return

```
<script>
  document.parent.cb12354(123);
</script>
```